# How to prevent copying of a certain file?

Tags: windows-7, windows

There are certain files in my system that i dont want someone to copy those in my presence. Can i prevent copying some files in Windows?

Comment: u mean don't want someone to copy those in your absence?

Comment: In general the answer is **no** -- but if you apply BitLocker encryption to your hard drive and turn off your computer, it will be very difficult for anyone to obtain the information without breaking your encryption password.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish yes !! They should be visible but no one should able to copy that.

Comment: you can either restrict access to it thru Folder/File Security or Encrypt it thru say BitLocker. But i'm not sure how you'll be able to make files visible, but non-copy-able.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it without the help of an outside utility. You can use BitLocker or use something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)